# Should I prefer Rcpp::NumericVector over std::vector?

Tags: c++, rcpp

Is there any reason why I should prefer `Rcpp::NumericVector` over `std::vector<double>`?

For example, the two functions below

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector foo(const Rcpp::NumericVector& x) {
  Rcpp::NumericVector tmp(x.length());
  for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
    tmp[i] = x[i] + 1.0;
  return tmp;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> bar(const std::vector<double>& x) {
  std::vector<double> tmp(x.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
    tmp[i] = x[i] + 1.0;
  return tmp;
}
```

Are equivalent when considering their working and benchmarked performance. I understand that Rcpp offers sugar and vectorized operations, but if it is only about taking R's vector as input and returning vector as output, then would there be any difference which one of those I use? Can using `std::vector<double>` lead to any possible problems when interacting with R?

Comment: I would _not_ say this is purely opinion based. There are some concerns that this question does raise (inadvertently).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Are equivalent when considering their working and benchmarked performance.

1. I doubt that the benchmarks are accurate because going from a `SEXP` to `std::vector<double>` requires a *deep* copy from one data structure to another. (And as I was typing this, @DirkEddelbuettel ran a microbenchmark.)
2. The markup of the Rcpp object (e.g. `const Rcpp::NumericVector& x`) is just visual sugar. By default, the object given is a pointer and as such can easily have a ripple modification effect (see below). Thus, there is no true match that exists with `const std::vector<double>& x` that effectively "locks" and "passes a references".

> Can using `std::vector<double>` lead to any possible problems when interacting with R?

In short, no. The only penalty that is paid is the transference between objects.

The gain over this transference is the fact that modifying a value of a `NumericVector` that is assigned to another `NumericVector` will not cause a domino update. In essence, each `std::vector<T>` is a direct copy of the other. Therefore, the following couldn't happen:

```
#include<Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test_copy(){
    NumericVector A = NumericVector::create(1, 2, 3);
    NumericVector B = A;

    Rcout << "Before: " << std::endl << "A: " << A << std::endl << "B: " << B << std::endl; 

    A[1] = 5; // 2 -> 5

    Rcout << "After: " << std::endl << "A: " << A << std::endl << "B: " << B << std::endl; 
}
```

Gives:

```
test_copy()
# Before: 
# A: 1 2 3
# B: 1 2 3
# After: 
# A: 1 5 3
# B: 1 5 3
```

> Is there any reason why I should prefer `Rcpp::NumericVector` over `std::vector<double>`?

There are a few reasons:

1. As hinted previously, using `Rcpp::NumericVector` avoids a *deep* copy to and fro the *C++* `std::vector<T>`.
2. You gain access to the *sugar* functions.
3. Ability to 'mark up' *Rcpp* object in *C++* (e.g. adding attributes via `.attr()`)

Comment: Good answer. Should mention that [RcppHoney](https://github.com/dcdillon/RcppHoney) by @dcdillon offers sugar for `std::vector<>` too.

Answer (score 24):

"If unsure, just time it."

All it takes is to add these few lines to the file you already had:

```
/*** R
library(microbenchmark)
x <- 1.0* 1:1e7   # make sure it is numeric
microbenchmark(foo(x), bar(x), times=100L)
*/
```

Then just calling `sourceCpp("...yourfile...")` generates the following result (plus warnings on signed/unsigned comparisons):

```
R> library(microbenchmark)

R> x <- 1.0* 1:1e7   # make sure it is numeric

R> microbenchmark(foo(x), bar(x), times=100L)
Unit: milliseconds
   expr     min      lq    mean  median      uq      max neval cld
 foo(x) 31.6496 31.7396 32.3967 31.7806 31.9186  54.3499   100  a 
 bar(x) 50.9229 51.0602 53.5471 51.1811 51.5200 147.4450   100   b
R>
```

Your `bar()` solution needs to make a copy to create a *R* object in the R memory pool. `foo()` does not.  That matters for *large* vectors that you run over *many times*. Here we see a ratio of close of about 1.8.

In practice, it may not matter if you prefer one coding style over the other etc pp.