# Passing an Armadillo sparse matrix by reference with Rcpp

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, rcpp, armadillo

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300048/rcpp-pass-by-reference-vs-by-value) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49272396/difference-between-value-and-reference-args-in-rcpp). The difference here is that I'm not passing an Rcpp type like `NumericVector` or `NumericMatrix`, but an `arma::sp_mat`.

Is there any way to pass an `sp_mat` to C++, modify its values, and have the changes show up in the original object in R?

This can be done with a `NumericMatrix`, for example:

```
cppFunction("void frob(NumericMatrix& x)
{
    for(NumericMatrix::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(*it != 0) *it = *it + 5;
    }
}")

M <- Matrix(0, 5, 1, sparse=TRUE)
M[1] <- 1.2345

m <- as.matrix(M)

frob(m)
m
       #[,1]
#[1,] 6.2345
#[2,] 0.0000
#[3,] 0.0000
#[4,] 0.0000
#[5,] 0.0000
```

The same technique works for an `arma::mat` dense matrix. But for a sparse matrix, it doesn't work:

```
cppFunction("void frob2(arma::sp_mat& x)
{
    for(arma::sp_mat::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++it)
    {
        *it = *it + 5;
    }
}", depends="RcppArmadillo")

frob2(M)
M
#5 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

#[1,] 1.2345
#[2,] .     
#[3,] .     
#[4,] .     
#[5,] .
```

Comment: Mmm, this might be a regression w.r.t the work done on the sparse importers done over this past summer.

Comment: @coatless interesting, so this isn't the intended behaviour? Is there a way to modify the matrix without making unnecessary copies?

Comment: Not sure we ever had reference semantics. After all, there is no native type for sparse matrices so something needs to be copied somewhere...

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately [there is no auxiliary memory constructor](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat) for sparse matrices in Armadillo.

However you can construct sparse matrix like structure in C++ using pointers to R objects. [Here is example](https://github.com/dselivanov/rsparse/blob/master/src/MappedSparseMatrices.h#L26):

```
template< typename T>
class MappedCSC {
public:
  MappedCSC();
  MappedCSC(std::uint32_t n_rows,
            std::uint32_t n_cols,
            size_t nnz,
            std::uint32_t * row_indices,
            std::uint32_t * col_ptrs,
            T * values):
    n_rows(n_rows), n_cols(n_cols), nnz(nnz), row_indices(row_indices), col_ptrs(col_ptrs), values(values) {};
  const std::uint32_t n_rows;
  const std::uint32_t n_cols;
  const size_t nnz;
  const std::uint32_t * row_indices;
  const std::uint32_t * col_ptrs;
  T * values;
};

using dMappedCSC = MappedCSC<double>;
```

[Here is how you can extract it](https://github.com/dselivanov/rsparse/blob/f488decc4d3cf3d2735a19ada96ba4559250a8d4/src/utils.cpp#L81):

```
dMappedCSC extract_mapped_csc(Rcpp::S4 input) {
  Rcpp::IntegerVector dim = input.slot("Dim");
  Rcpp::NumericVector values = input.slot("x");
  uint32_t nrows = dim[0];
  uint32_t ncols = dim[1];
  Rcpp::IntegerVector row_indices = input.slot("i");
  Rcpp::IntegerVector col_ptrs = input.slot("p");
  return dMappedCSC(nrows, ncols, values.length(), (uint32_t *)row_indices.begin(), (uint32_t *)col_ptrs.begin(), values.begin());
}
```

And [here is example](https://github.com/dselivanov/rsparse/blob/f488decc4d3cf3d2735a19ada96ba4559250a8d4/src/ProductSparseDense.cpp#L32) on how to iterate column by column:

```
Rcpp::NumericMatrix dense_csc_prod(const Rcpp::NumericMatrix &x_r, const Rcpp::S4 &y_csc_r) {
  const arma::dmat x = arma::dmat((double *)&x_r[0], x_r.nrow(), x_r.ncol(), false, false);
  const dMappedCSC y_csc = extract_mapped_csc(y_csc_r);
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix res(x.n_rows, y_csc.n_cols);
  arma::dmat res_arma_map = arma::dmat(res.begin(), res.nrow(), res.ncol(), false, false);
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < y_csc.n_cols; i++) {
    const uint32_t p1 = y_csc.col_ptrs[i];
    const uint32_t p2 = y_csc.col_ptrs[i + 1];
    // mapped indices are uint32_t, but arma only allows indices be uvec = vec<uword> = vec<size_t>
    // so we need to construct these indices by copying from uint32_t to uword
    const arma::Col<uint32_t> idx_temp = arma::Col<uint32_t>(&y_csc.row_indices[p1], p2 - p1);
    const arma::uvec idx = arma::conv_to<arma::uvec>::from(idx_temp);
    const arma::colvec y_csc_col = arma::colvec(&y_csc.values[p1], p2 - p1, false, false);
    res_arma_map.col(i) = x.cols(idx) * y_csc_col;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Very nice. How abou turning that into a post for the Rcpp Gallery?