# Does converting vectors between Rcpp and C++ (using Rcpp::as or Rcpp::wrap) create a new vector and copy elements?

Tags: c++, r, vector, rcpp

In my understanding, converting vectors between Rcpp and C++ creates new vectors as follows. Is my understanding right?

When converting an Rcpp vector to a C++ vector, we use `Rcpp::as<T>()` (e.g. `Rcpp::as<std::string>` for `Rcpp::CharacterVector`).
`std::vector<std::string>` is created, and the original Rcpp elements are copied into the C++ vector as `std::string`. 
This means that modifying the newly created C++ vector elements does not affect the original Rcpp vector elements.

When converting a C++ vector to an Rcpp vector, we use `Rcpp::wrap()`.
Rcpp vector with the corresponding type is created, and the C++ elements are copied into the Rcpp vector as Rcpp objects. This means that modifying the newly created Rcpp vector elements does not affect the original C++ vector elements.

Comment: "It depends". On the type on the R side, and on the type on the C++ side.

Comment: "It depends"... OK.... I think I need to ask in a more specific way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Correct, the following functions perform conversions:

```
// conversion from R to C++
Rcpp::as<T>();
// conversion from C++ to R
Rcpp::wrap();
```

In short, moving data from an Rcpp object into a C++ vector and vice versa causes a copy to be made. This has been explained a bit here:

[Declare a variable as a reference in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363076/declare-a-variable-as-a-reference-in-rcpp)

For more on the templating, please see the [Rcpp Extending](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf) vignette.

Details on cost from an `Rcpp::*Vector` to `std::vector<T>` can be found here:

[Should I prefer Rcpp::NumericVector over std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602024/should-i-prefer-rcppnumericvector-over-stdvector/41602289#41602289)

One way to avoid the copy is to re-use memory if possible. This is hinted at here:

[Deciding between NumericVector and arma::vec in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170166/deciding-between-numericvector-and-armavec-in-rcpp/50181097#50181097)

Comment: As a reply to this question, the author of Rcpp says "it depends".

Comment: I'm a little confused, but I need to ask  in a more specific way.